# Kendo UI Grid Only Expand One Row at a Time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid which I would like to only be able to expand one row at a time for detail editing.  What is the simplest way to do this?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()
   .Name("MyGrid")
   .ClientDetailTemplateId("MyTemplate")
   .Columns(columns =>
   {
       columns.Bound(b => b.Code);
       columns.Bound(b => b.Name);
       columns.Bound(b => b.Description);
       ...
       columns.Command(cmd => { cmd.Edit(); cmd.Destroy(); });
   })
   .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
   .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
   .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .Model(model => model.Id(a => a.Id))
      .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "SysMaint", new { id = Model.ProjectId }))
      .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "SysMaint", new { projectId = Model.ProjectId }))
      .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "SysMaint"))
      .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "SysMaint"))
   )
)

<script id="MyTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
       .Name("TabStrip_#=Id#")
       .SelectedIndex(0)
       .Items(items =>
           {
               items.Add().Text("A").LoadContentFrom("MyPartialA", "SysMaint", new { id = "#=Id#" });
               items.Add().Text("B").LoadContentFrom("MyPartialB", "SysMaint", new { id = "#=Id#" });
           })
       .ToClientTemplate()
    )
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ends up this is really simple.  Just add these few lines.

```
      ...
      .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "SysMaint"))
      .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "SysMaint"))
   )
   .Events(events => events.DetailExpand("detailExpand"))
)

<script type="text/javascript">
    var expandedRow;
    function detailExpand(e) {
        // Only one open at a time
        if (expandedRow != null && expandedRow[0] != e.masterRow[0]) {
            var grid = $('#MyGrid').data('kendoGrid');
            grid.collapseRow(expandedRow);
        }
        expandedRow = e.masterRow;
    }
</script>
```

I hope this helps somebody.

Comment: You could use $(e.sender.wrapper).data('kendoGrid') instead of harcoding the grid name. This will then work with any grid.

Answer (score 5):

That works except it does not remove the old detail row. Add the bit marked NEW to remove each previously opened detail row.

```
if (expandedRow != null && expandedRow != e.masterRow[0]) {
    var grid = $('#RequestsGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    grid.collapseRow(expandedRow);
    expandedRow[0].nextElementSibling.remove(); //NEW
}
expandedRow = e.masterRow;
```

Comment: I added your new line.  In my case it then makes the row so it can not be opened again.  BUT, I think you have a good idea - I wonder if a variation of this could solve the multi-child-grid-in-edit-mode-problem.

Comment: hmm thats odd. I am using that variation for my app. are you being sure to use your grid id for var grid?

Comment: For those of us stuck in IE land, `expandedRow[0].nextElementSibling.remove();` can be replaced with its jQuery equivalent `expandedRow.next().remove();`

Answer (score 3):

Building on Trey's answer, this version will work generically for any grid (using @vikasde's suggestion), and will also work when you have nested grids, so that the child grid when invoking the detailExpand, won't collapse its parent grid row as a side effect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function detailExpand(ev) {
        var expandedRow = $(ev.sender.wrapper).data('expandedRow');
        // Only one open at a time
        if (expandedRow && expandedRow[0] != ev.masterRow[0]) {
            var grid = $(ev.sender.wrapper).data('kendoGrid');
            grid.collapseRow(expandedRow);
        }
        $(ev.sender.wrapper).data('expandedRow', ev.masterRow);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to the answers already here, I found that by combining hatchet's and Danny Blue's answers and using the `DetailCollapse` event works nicely, and will remove the underlying detail content if a row is collapsed manually.

MVC Grid configuration:

```
.Events(ev =>
    {
      ev.DetailExpand("detailExpand");
      ev.DetailCollapse("detailCollapse");
    })
```

Page scripts:

```
function detailExpand(ev) { // Credit hatchet
    var expandedRow = $(ev.sender.wrapper).data('expandedRow');
    // Only one open at a time
    if (expandedRow && expandedRow[0] !== ev.masterRow[0]) {
        var $grid = $(ev.sender.wrapper).data('kendoGrid');
        $grid.collapseRow(expandedRow);
    }
    $(ev.sender.wrapper).data('expandedRow', ev.masterRow);
}
function detailCollapse(ev) {
    var expandedRow = $(ev.sender.wrapper).data('expandedRow');
    expandedRow.next().remove(); // Credit Danny Blue
}
```